# 500 Server Error, Don't know Why

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis

I made a virtual machine on azure to host my asp.net mvc 5 website. I made a directory in iis on the machine and pointed it to my domain. I first put the default iis.html page and went to it. This works.

Now I put all my asp.net mvc code in that folder and I get "500 server error". I don't know why.

I tried to put in my web config

```
<customErrors mode="Off">
```

Yet this did nothing. I don't know why it is failing nor how to check. There is nothing special with this website(just controllers and views...not even a database).

I am not sure if I need to install anything more to get it to work. The vm is windows server 2012.

Comment: make sure you add <customErrors mode="Off"> in the root web.config, and not the one in views folder

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Verify installed MVC version in the server (windows\ assembly folder)
2. Verify application bin folder which should contain appropriate dll(s)  (website/ virtual directory maps to a physical folder, bin should be under the root with required binaries)
3. Also verify MVC views ('Views' folder should be just under the root)
4. Verify Web.config, which should be updated properly
5. Application Pool should be running under appropriate .Net version (Run -> inetmgr -> Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> .Net Framework Version)

Comment: How do I verify this stuff?

Comment: Follow the steps which are described above.